# RecyclerView with multiple view types explanation needed

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using kotlin and I am starting to understand how a recyclerview with multiple view types works.

From what i understand, there are two methods

1. To create multiple Viewholder and use a when statement (Java switch) in the OnCreateViewHolder to differentiate when what viewholder should be used. -> also overriding the getItemViewType function and bind the data in the OnBindViewHolder.
2. To make multiple adapters (for each viewtype one) and use adapter concatenate or whatever it was called.

Now what i want to know is when should i use what method? What is better for my app i am coding? Is one method better then the other?

Can someone explain me when to use what method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you create 1 adapter and different viewHolders. Every viewHolder serves it's viewtype and has it's own inflated xml.

Every item of the list that you are feeding to your adapter has to have a viewType, so when you are about to "draw" a list item you send it to the correct viewHolder to inflate it.

Do not use more than one adapters, it will get messy and hard to maintain.

Comment: okey, so it is not common to use multiple adapters. Understand. Thanks for explaining